# How can I create a MediaStream track from a continuous stream of images in node.js? (for usage with WebRTC)

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mediastream

I want to stream a robot cam from a web media element. I have access to the camera in node.js, which is providing a live stream of images (continually producing a new frame at ~20fps).

In this same situation in the browser, one could write the image to a canvas and capture the stream.

Is there some way to construct a MediaStreamTrack object that can be directly added to the RTCPeerConnection, without having to use browser-only `captureStream` or `getUserMedia` APIs?

I've tried the npm module `canvas`, which is supposed to port `canvas` to node -- then maybe I could captureStream the canvas after writing the image to it. But that didn't work.

I'm using the `wrtc` node WebRTC module with the `simple-peer` wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `video-compositing` example here.

https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples